# Adding dynamic obstacles in Stage

Tags: simulation, rviz, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have attempted two ways to add a dynamic obstacle neither of which have worked:

1. I added a simple model and added a velocity attribute to it which should give it an initial velocity as mentioned [here](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/stage-cvs/group__model.html). But for some reason that I have not understood, this method is not working.
2. I added another position model (thus making it two robots in my simulation) so that I can try to pass messages to my dynamic obstacle through the robot_1/cmd_vel topic. After debugging the many tf errors that come I have finally got rid of errors in rviz. However the obstacles are not visible in rviz even though they are visible in Stage. Not sure how to solve this error either.

Any help will be highly appreciated. If you require any additional information to help understand the problem then I can add them at the earliest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255348/adding-dynamic-obstacles-in-stage/) by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was ultimately able to get the dynamic obstacles working although I don't entirely remember how. I think publishing velocity commands to it from the terminal were working although the same messages were not working when published from a node. But that;s how I got around the situation.

---

Originally posted by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) with karma: 115 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0